# Android: How to set static value before onCreate is called

Tags: android

I want to have an "option" set before the Activity is created or at least before it starts. If there is a way to do this via the AndroidManifest? Consider this example where we have a global config class that is used in onCreate to instantiate an object (not fully OO for brevity)

```
public class Global {
    public static boolean visible = false;
}
```

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // here is where we want the most up-to-date value of visible
        MyObject obj = new MyObject(Global.visible);
    }
}
```

Obviously in this case "visible" would be "false". If this were some sort of API library, we would like to provide the option for users to set "visible" to "true".

**Update 1**

The objective is to have the global class in a pre-compiled library and have its value set by a developer utilizing the library. I am looking for easiest way for the developer to do this when they create their application; I think the manifest is the probably the way to go but I don't know how to inject the value for "visible" via the xml. The answers below using preferences are good but only cover the users point-of-view.

**Update 2**
IMHO using resources works best here.

```
<bool name="visible">true</bool>
```

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // here is where we want the most up-to-date value of visible
        Resource res = getResource();
        MyObject obj = new MyObject(res.getBoolean(R.bool.visible));
    }
}
```

Comment: Not using compiled defaults class `Global`, but updated answer with way for developers to update (without having to modify the reference in `MyActivity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using SharedPreferences would do what you are looking for, using `Global.visible` as the default value. Then if the user changes it to `true`, it will use that value.

```
boolean makeVisible = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean(
  "MyVisiblePreference",
  Global.visible);
MyObject obj = new MyObject(makeVisible);
```

---

To allow the preference to be updatable without re-compiling or setting (through a Preferences activity), you can load the default preference from `resources`:

```
<bool name="MyVisiblePreference">true</bool>
```

And reference it similarly with:

```
boolean makeVisible = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean(
   "MyVisiblePreference",
   getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.MyVisiblePreference));
```

If the developer does not set the preference to `false`, it will default to `true` (based upon the `resources` value).

Comment: Using a Resource file was the best solution in my case, so your answer certainly led me in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

For simple objects you can create them like this: (Based off of your code example)

```
public static boolean visible = false;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // here is where we want the most up-to-date value of visible
        MyObject obj = new MyObject(Global.visible);
    }
}
```

For a more complex object you can initialize it with a [static initializer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) like this:

```
public static boolean visible;

static {
    visible = false;
}

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // here is where we want the most up-to-date value of visible
        MyObject obj = new MyObject(Global.visible);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is an option for a developer but it would require them to recompile / modify their source.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `android.app.Application`, this class has method `onCreate` that you can override. Your subclass have to be defined in `AndroidManifest.xml` in `<application name="YourApplication">`. `onCreate` of application is called before all other components in your application are created (before any `Activity` or `Service`).

Comment: Interesting, do you have an example of how to inject the value on the on overridden class via the xml?